# Loading from json into HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, json

so I am doing a small project in which I need to put some data about products into a json file, and then load that data into the JavaScript section of the html code. The problem is that I keep getting errors like Microsoft Visual Code is telling me that the object I am trying to load is underfined.
Here is my JSON file:

```
{    
"Data" : 
[        
{"Name": "Widget", "Price": 25.00, "Quantity": 5 },
{"Name": "Thing", "Price": 15.00, "Quantity": 5 },        
{"Name": "Doodad", "Price": 5.00, "Quantity": 10 } 
]
```

}

And here is my code from the HTML page.

```
<form id="form1">
What product do you wish to search for? <input name="name" type="text" size="20">
</form>
<button onclick="outputprodus()">Submit
</button>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Vlad.json"></script>

<script>
    var userdata = JSON.parse(Data);
    var produs1_nume = userdata[0].Name;
    var produs1_pret = userdata[0].Price;
    var produs1_cantitate = userdata[0].Quantity;



    function outputprodus(){
    var x, y;
    x=document.getElementById("form1");
    y=x.elements["name"].value;
    document.write(y+" este produsul cautat.");
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(produs1_nume+" costa "+produs1_pret+" pentru "+produs1_cantitate+" bucati");
    }
</script>
```

Am I loading the data wrong, or making some mistake afterwards?

Comment: What do you get if  you `console.log(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were loading json as script.
Here is how to load a file from network.

Codepen: https://codepen.io/kishin-karra/pen/ExVqzRw?editors=1010

```
var userdata = null;
var produs1_nume = null;
var produs1_pret = null;
var produs1_cantitate = null;

fetch('https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/com.instadl.test-assets-123/Vlad.json').then(res => {
    res.json().then((data) => {
        userdata = data.Data;
        produs1_nume = userdata[0].Name;
        produs1_pret = userdata[0].Price;
        produs1_cantitate = userdata[0].Quantity;
    })
})

function outputprodus() {
    var x, y;
    x = document.getElementById("form1");
    y = x.elements["name"].value;
    document.write(y + " este produsul cautat.");
    document.write("<br>");
    document.write(produs1_nume + " costa " + produs1_pret + " pentru " + produs1_cantitate + " bucati");
}
```

Comment: When I modify the json file in the way you advised me to, I get an error on the "var" saying that "Expected a JSON object, array or literal."

Comment: you do not need to edit the json file. You need to code in javascript. Wait editing the answer

Comment: You just need to change the first line in your javascript code: JSON.parse(data) => JSON.parse(Data).Data

Comment: Unfortunately, the result I get still says:

"underfined costa underfined pentru underfined bucati."

Basically the produs1_nume, produs1_pret and produs1_cantitate variables are not retrieved correctly or something like that. I am trying to use an external JavaScript file now. Maybe I am messing something up while working with in-line script in HTML.

Comment: If you could share a codepen, I can help you correct it.

Comment: If you have Vlad.json hosted somewhere, I can create a quick codepen for you

Comment: Just observed, You cannot load json in a script tag. Please use fetch API in javascript. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: https://codepen.io/Ciuboss/pen/WNQVBzb   The problem is that I do not have an actualy JavaScript file. I just write it in HTML. The thing written there for the JavaScript, are actually what is in my json file.

Comment: I have hosted the JSON. Have created a new codepen. I shall update the answer

Comment: Have added a codepen. Just wait a few seconds before clicking the submiit button. let the json load from network

Comment: Damn man. Thanks for wasting so much time to assist me. I'm trying to implement it in my program. Will get back in a couple of minutes to tell you how it went. But either way, thanks a lot for all the assistance!

Comment: please mark it as correct if it solves your purpose. Thanks :)

Comment: Well, I had some issues cause I got the error that fetch is undefined so I had to install some extensions and stuff(obviously I have not coded in too long). I added this line "const fetch = require("node-fetch");" before the fetch(URL) line because otherwise it would not work. And now I run the code for the js and it's OK, but when I run the HTML, the page opens but the Submit button does not do anything unfortunately. Really annoying cause I can see that it works in your codepen, so it must be some bad settings on my part.